# Android Studio (Electric Eel | 2022.1.1) does not show "fragment_first.xml" in layout

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

I'm a complete beginner at android development, and have been learning the basics from developer.android.com

In task 4, it says that we have to open `fragment_first.xml` under res>layout, which I cannot find anywhere. Reading further says `Troubleshooting: If you don't see the file fragment_first.xml, confirm you are running Android Studio 3.6 or later, which is required for this codelab.`
I've been trying to find if my Android Studio is 3.6 or less for the past hour, and I don't know if what I'm doing is wrong or not anymore. Please help!

please ignore the project name

[image: resouce manager]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your resource manager (The bar on the left showing all the files in your project). You are using the newest version of Android Studio so I think your version is fine :)

- edit: thanks for the screenshot, so normally the file should be exactly where you highlighted, in this case I'd just make file myself and name it the same.

Comment: 2/2 you can add the file by right clicking the layout folder and selecting: `new > Layout Resource File` and add the filename.

Just to confirm, you also have the FirstFragment.kt/java in your project right? if not you might also need to make that.

Comment: @Robin What about the content of the file? I don't know what it's supposed to contain, will it be auto-generated?

Comment: @2/2 no i dont, i've looked everywhere

Comment: What is the url to the tutorial you're following?

Comment: nevermind, i made a new project with a different template and it fixed itself...?

Comment: How to close a question?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96281/how-to-close-a-question-in-stackoverflow-com